# Is it possible to specify the type of binding value in angularjs 1.5(6) using typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to specify the type of binding items. so that I can use component just like a function.

for example. we have an component

```js
angular.module('app').component('navBar', new NavBar());

 class NavBar{
    public bindings:{};
    constructor(){
        this.bindings={ 
            navInfo:'<'
        }
    }
}
```

and the expected data is

```js
export interface INavInfo {
    text: string;
    icon: string;
    OnClick: Function;
}
```

what I expect to pass in is (otherwise it will complain error input)

```
{
  text: 'Maintenance',
  icon: 'assessment',
  OnClick: () => {....}
}
```

is there a way we could constrain the type pass in `navInfo` is the type of `INavInfo` ?

Comment: What you mean with _pass in_ `navInfo`? Where in your code you are _passing in_ this data to the component?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see clearly by your code "where" you want TypeScript compile to break. I guess this has a lot to do with you *pass in* the navInfo information.

Let's get the *hero* example in the angular documentation for *components*
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

The way I see you *pass in* data to the components in that example is in `index.js` file:

```
angular.module('heroApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl() {
    this.hero = {
    name: 'Spawn'
  };
});
```

In this example, the only way to use **TypeScript** for ensuring you are passing all details correctly to your component is marking `this.hero` variable as type `INavInfo` in your TS controller:

```
private hero: INavInfo;
```

If someone *forgets* to use this specific type in another controller and use the same component, your TypeScript compile won't break at all.

On the other hand, suppose everyone's doing a great job and explicitly declaring `INavInfo` everywhere you use this component... all places using this type will break *when* you need to change a property name or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right.
navInfo is member of the component bindings declaration and 
You would like to do...

```
<nav-bar navInfo="vm.navInfo"></nav-bar>
```

in the view
and "vm.navInfo" to be type-checked
against INavInfo.

Then the answer is no.

Because you will instantiate your component within a HTML view ,
 and as far as I know there is no tool currently ,
 supporting that scenario ,
 of validating checking typescript in HTML markup .
neither angular provide type to the binding , is simple declaring the 'key' to bind to and its binding behavior.
because is not supported by a language feature but an angular convention

even if you declare your component with
inline html holding all the code in one file
in Webstorm, which is very angular 1.x friendly

but you could add run-time checking ( I don't think its good idea tho...)

```
import * as angular from "angular";

export  interface INavInfo {
    text: string;
    icon: string;
    OnClick: Function;
}

function isNavInfo(x: any): x is INavInfo {
    return x && typeof x.text === "string"
        && typeof x.icon === "string"
        && typeof x.OnClick === "function";
}

class NavBar implements angular.IController {

    navInfo?: INavInfo;

    $onInit = () => {

    };

    $onChanges? = (onChangesObj: angular.IOnChangesObject) => {
        if (this.navInfo && !isNavInfo(this.navInfo)) {
            throw "Nav Info is Not NavInfo";
        }
    };

    clicked = ()=> {
        if(this.navInfo && this.navInfo.OnClick){
            this.navInfo.OnClick();
        }
    }
}

class OtherController {
    navInfo: INavInfo ;
    constructor(){
        this.navInfo = {
            text: "Hello",
            icon: "home",
            OnClick: ()=>{
                console.log("link clicked!")
            }
        };
    }
} 

angular.module('NavBarTest', [])
    .component(
        'navBar', {
            template: `<!-- there's No Type Checking here -->
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class="navText" href="" ng-click="$ctrl.clicked">
                                {{$ctrl.navInfo.text}}
                                <i class="naIvIcon">{{$ctrl.navInfo.icon}}</i>
                                </a>                        
                            </li>
                       </ul>>`,
            bindings: {
                navInfo: '<'
            },
            controller: NavBar,
            // controllerAs: '$ctrl'
        }
    )
    .component("navBarUser", {
        template: ` <!-- there's No Type Checking here -->
            <nav-bar nav-info="$ctrl.navInfo" ></nav-bar>
        `,
        controller: OtherController,
        // controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    });
```